# How to override xib as cumtom view?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I have one xib file(SuperViewA) and super class(SuperViewA).

```
class SuperViewA: UIView {
private let aaa: ...

   init(aaa: AAA) {
      self.aaa = aaa
      super.init(frame: .zero)
   }

   required init(coder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: coder)   // <- It's an error because of property aaa is not initialized.
}
```

Then, I want to subclass SuperViewA named SubViewA.

```
class SubViewA: SuperViewA {
...
}
```

SubViewA's UI is just same with SuperViewA's xib.
So, I don't need to make SubViewA.xib.
But I need to override superclass's initializer because of an initialized object from subclass is needed in the superclass.

If I make SubViewA's xib, SuperViewA's UI(xib) is not overriden. So, below code will be crashed.

```
let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: SubViewA.self), owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? SubViewA
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why not making a class extension instead of subclass ?

Comment: @PtitXav I will use SuperViewA class as common class. So, I'm going to make subclasses of SuperViewA like SubViewA, SubViewB, SubViewC...